# Unable to assign value to php array

Tags: php

I am creating an array in php by assigning values retrieved from database. When I print the array it is displaying array as output and not its contents. However it does retrieve values from mysql.

```
$resultset=mysql_query("select isbn from tbl_book where publisherid='$publisherid'");
/***Retrieve Books*****/
while($resultISBNArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
{
$isbn = $resultISBNArray["isbn"];
$myArr[]=$isbn;
}
echo $myArr
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo`ing any array always prints "Array". You need to pick individual values in the array (`echo $myArr[0]`) or use something like [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can not print an array. You have todo something like `var_dump($myArr);`